# finding unique items in an excel list

Tags: excel, unique

I am trying to count the unique number of entries in a pivot table.

My pivot table is displayed as such:

```
U       V           W       X           Y       Z    AA
PN#     Customer    Offer#  Date        $       QTY  Sum of Offer#
123456  00000001    157815  09.06.2015  16,3    25   1
123456  00000001    157815  09.06.2015  31      10   1
123456  00000001    157815  09.06.2015  43,5    5    1
123456  00000001    157815  09.06.2015  65,3    1    1
123456  00000002    156682  31.03.2015  10      140  1
123456  00000003    157505  19.05.2015  20      25   1
123456  00000004    156925  13.04.2015  10,04   1000 1
123456  00000004    157459  18.05.2015  9,44    1000 1
123456  00000005    158036  23.06.2015  16,3    25   1
123456  00000006    157064  20.04.2015  10,8    100  1
123456  00000006    157064  20.04.2015  12,5    50   1
123456  00000007    156616  26.03.2015  9,5     700  1
123456  00000007    157264  29.04.2015  9,3     450  1
```

This is basically a list of order offers we make to customers. I want to analyse this to see how often we offer products etc

So far, I have the number of total offers using:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($U$5:$U$7000=U5),$AA$5:$AA$7000)
```

this shows for one article number, how many offers there are. But of course, it counts the duplicates as well.

So I am testing with COUNTIF:

`=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF($W$5:$W$45,$W$5:$W$45))`   (sample fixed range - normally will goto row 7000)

and this works for a fixed range.

So, my question is - **how to combine those two?** - so that I can see for one Product Number PN#... the unique number of offers made. I can of course then use the same fomula to see unique number of customers, which at present is also not possible.

Thanks!

Comment: I can combine the two formulas. Yet, I presume you want to make the formula that you would be able to use without setting its range all the time the data changes? like $W$5:$W$65536?

Comment: best would be no set range, but to be honest, it would be fine with. Can you show me how to combine them?

Comment: or to clarify, i want to combine the two features... the sumproduct to check if the product ID matches, and the COUNTIF to check the unique numbers. When I combine like the following, I get strange decimal numbers...    =SUMPRODUCT(--($U$5:$U$7000=U5)*$AA$5:$AA$7000)/COUNTIF($V$5:$V$7000,$V$5:$V$7000)